# virtualenv doesn't create PYTHONPATH / pip installed packages don't work

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I'm using virtualenv 1.9.1 on cygwin under win 7. Each virtualenv is created without any options (other than the directory name, obviously). There are no fancy customisations.

All virtualenvs are fresh, in the sense that I have not created any wrapper scripts, nor edited any of the virtualenv scripts. I am completely certain that I am not doing anything special (i.e. other than misusing virtualenv, rather than taking action which frustrates its operation) which is causing PYTHONPATH to be absent in multiple virtualenvs.

The virtualenv activate script for each new virtualenv does not create a PYTHONPATH. pip installs packages under `$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/<packagedir>` (e.g. `lib/python2.7/site-packages/html5lib`).

pip's behaviour seems desirable. **However, running python (after activating the virtualenv) results in no pip-installed packages being loadable (i.e. "no module named ...").**

Update: Adding a PYTHONPATH to `activate` does indeed "solve" the problem. Obviously, I don't want to manually maintain this, nor have to update `activate_this.py`. I would still like to know why virtualenvs now do not work straight out of the box.

What's the solution? virtualenv never used to do this. What's wrong with it now?

Update 2: Here is the output of running virtualenv with -vv:

```
$ virtualenv -vv newvirtualenv
Creating newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7
Symlinking Python bootstrap modules
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/config
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/os.py
  Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: posix
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
  Cannot import bootstrap module: nt
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/ntpath.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/fnmatch.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/locale.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/encodings
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/stat.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
  File newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.dll already exists
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/types.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/re.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/sre.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
  File newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.dll already exists
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/abc.py
  Symlinking newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
Creating newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Writing newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site.py
Writing newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/orig-prefix.txt
Writing newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/no-global-site-packages.txt
Creating parent directories for newvirtualenv/include
Symlinking newvirtualenv/include/python2.7
Creating newvirtualenv/bin
New python executable in newvirtualenv/bin/python2.7
Changed mode of newvirtualenv/bin/python2.7 to 0755
Also creating executable in newvirtualenv/bin/python
Changed mode of newvirtualenv/bin/python to 0755
Testing executable with newvirtualenv/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys;out=sys.stdout;getattr(out, "buffer", out).write(sys.prefix.encode("utf-8"))"
Got sys.prefix result: u'/cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv'
Creating newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/distutils
Writing newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py
Writing newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/distutils/distutils.cfg
Using existing setuptools egg: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Installing setuptools...
  Running command /cygdrive/c/Users/ma...ualenv/bin/python2.7 -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])






" -v /usr/lib/python2.7/s...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
  Processing setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
  Copying setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg to /cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  Adding setuptools 0.6c11 to easy-install.pth file
  Saving /cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth
  Installing easy_install script to /cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv/bin
  changing mode of /cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv/bin/easy_install to 755
  Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv/bin
  changing mode of /cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv/bin/easy_install-2.7 to 755

  Installed /cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
  Processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
  Finished processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
...Installing setuptools...done.
Installing existing pip-1.3.1.tar.gz distribution: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.3.1.tar.gz
Installing pip...
  Running command /cygdrive/c/Users/ma...ualenv/bin/python2.7 -x /cygdrive/c/Users/ma...env/bin/easy_install /usr/lib/python2.7/s...ort/pip-1.3.1.tar.gz
  Processing pip-1.3.1.tar.gz
  Running pip-1.3.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ZP_VIv/pip-1.3.1/egg-dist-tmp-H3XBh_
  warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.txt' found under directory 'docs/_build'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build/_sources'
  Adding pip 1.3.1 to easy-install.pth file
  Installing pip script to /cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv/bin
  Installing pip-2.7 script to /cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv/bin

  Installed /cygdrive/c/Users/marcin/Documents/codeprojects/newvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
  Processing dependencies for pip==1.3.1
  Finished processing dependencies for pip==1.3.1
...Installing pip...done.
Writing newvirtualenv/bin/activate
Writing newvirtualenv/bin/activate.fish
Writing newvirtualenv/bin/activate_this.py
Writing newvirtualenv/bin/activate.csh
```

Comment: Ugly solution: maybe hack the `activate` script and add path there manually?

Comment: @JakubM. That occurred to me, but this seems like either I'm not doing something else obvious, or a bug in the current version of virtualenv.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is a red herring. It is **not** set by `activate`. It never is. The python executable in `bin/python.exe` is responsible for setting `PYTHONHOME` (internally) instead. Can you run `virtualenv -vv` (so two `-v` options) and show us this debug output in your question to help us debug the problem?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Done. I hope this is illuminating, because I see nothing obviously wrong.

Comment: Which python/virtualenv executables are you running? virtualenv is not avaliable as a package in cygwin, so what executable are you running when you run `virtualenv newve`? Are you using cygwin's python package? Or python.org's native Windows python? Did you install virtualenv with a setup.exe or something? The point of all these questions is I'm wondering if you're mixing and matching cygwin installed things with things installed outside of cygwin.

Comment: @snapshoe Cygwin python, `virtualenv` installed  at `/usr/bin/virtualenv` using `pip`; `pip` installed with `easy_install`; `easy_install` being the version packaged with cygwin python. There's no mixing and matching.

Comment: I don't see `easy_install` installed with cygwin anywhere. I had to create ve's with `python ...\virtualenv.py <name>`. I agree with @MartijnPieters-- PYTHONPATH is completely unrelated to the issue. I have ve's created with cygwin's python 2.x and 3.x, and they both import virtualenv-installed packages fine, and nowhere is PYTHONPATH ever set.

Comment: @snapshoe `easy_install` is installed for me at `/usr/bin/easy_install` (when not in an activated virtualenv).

Comment: I'm on Win7, running cygwin's Python. I've installed easy_install with [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/7282/how-to-run-easy-install-in-cygwin). Then pip, then virtualenv. Then ran `virtualenv newve`, then `source newve/bin/activate`, then pip installed a package (IPython). Everything works fine. I can import from python REPL, and the program works, and the paths are set correctly. And PYTHONPATH is never set anywhere. I'm at a loss.

Comment: @snapshoe Which answer? Cygwin definitely comes with a setuptools package, which is where my easy_install came from.

Comment: @snapshoe Well, reinstalling all of those elements does seem to have solved the problem. If you care to write an answer, I'll award the bounty to you if no-one comes up with something more illuminating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on Win7, running cygwin's Python. I've installed easy_install with [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/7282/how-to-run-easy-install-in-cygwin). Then pip, then virtualenv. Then ran `virtualenv newve`, then `source newve/bin/activate`, then pip installed a package (IPython). Everything works fine. I can import from python REPL, and the program works, and the paths are set correctly. And PYTHONPATH is never set anywhere. I'm at a loss.

Try reinstalling everything?

Edit:

Found out easy_install is available in the cygwin package `python-setuptools`.

Comment: I actually used the version downloaded directly from pypi instead of the python-setuptools when I reinstalled. I don't know if that is the culprit or not.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that PYTHONPATH is already set. Since Cygwin inherits all of Windows's environment variables, if PYTHONPATH is already set, virtualenv will use that instead of the proper directory. Check to see if under Windows PYTHONPATH is already set. If it is, delete it and try virtualenv again. Also check your .bashrc file to see if PYTHONPATH is set there. Why is it that you cannot use the normal Python for Windows? Are you writing a POSIX script?

Comment: To be clear: PYTHONPATH is absent. It is not set in the environment. I'm using cygwin because I prefer to use cygwin as a development environment.

Comment: @Marcin: Hmm...odd. Can you try to see if it will work at all in Windows? If so, then we know it is a problem in either Cygwin or Cygwin's Python. If not, then I am totally clueless. You could always use `sys.path.append` if all else fails.

Comment: I am using windows. Cygwin is windows.

Comment: @Marcin: I am saying outside of Cygwin. Just to see if the problem lies in either Cygwin or Cygwin's Python. :)